# switching implementation in runtime

Tags: java, reflection, runtime

I'm writing simple Chat System. There are should be two implementations of communication:

- using *Serialization*
- and *XML* (own protocol).

Implementation is chosen by user in GUI.

So, is it okay to use *if-else* or *switch* for choosing implementation ? 

 I have thought about Java Reflection but I can't figure out how to realize it. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: What about the [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)?

Comment: If you're using HTTP, you can also specify the MIME type in the header and use that to select which implementation to use in deserialization via `Content-Type`. (See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it can be "okay" to use a if-else or switch statement to choose the implementation. A better (and more OOP) approach would be something along these lines:

```java
//////////////////////////////////
// The communication interfaces
//////////////////////////////////

public interface IChatCommunicationFactory {
    public String toString();
    public IChatCommunication create();
}

public interface IChatCommunication {
    public sendChatLine(String chatLine);
    public registerChatLineReceiver(IChatLineReceiver chatLineReceiver);
}

public interface IChatLineReceiver {
    public void onChatLineReceived(String chatLine);
}

//////////////////////////////////
// The communication interface implementations
//////////////////////////////////

public class XMLChatCommunicationFactory implements IChatCommunicationFactory {
    public String toString() {
        return "XML implementation";
    }

    public IChatCommunication create() {
        return new XMLChatCommunication();
    }
}

public class XMLChatCommunication implements IChatCommunication {
    private XMLProtocolSocket socket;

    public XMLChatCommunication() {
        // set up socket
    }

    public sendChatLine(String chatLine) {
        // send your chat line
    }

    public registerChatLineReceiver(IChatLineReceiver chatLineReceiver) {
        // start thread in which received chat lines are handled and then passed to the onChatLineReceived of the IChatLineReceiver
    }
}

// Do the same as above for the Serialization implementation.


//////////////////////////////////
// The user interface
//////////////////////////////////

public void fillListBoxWithCommuncationImplementations(ListBox listBox) {
    listBox.addItem(new XMLChatCommunicationFactory());
    listBox.addItem(new SerializationChatCommunicationFactory());
}

public IChatCommunication getChatCommunicationImplementationByUserSelection(ListBox listBox) {
    if (listBox.selectedItem == null)
        return null;

    IChatCommunicationFactory factory = (IChatCommunicationFactory)listBox.selectedItem;
    return factory.create();
}
```

You could go one step further and implement something like a `ChatCommunicationFactoryRegistry` where each `IChatCommunicationFactory` is registerd. That would help to move the "business" logic out of the user interface because the `fillListBoxWithCommuncationImplementations()` method would only need to know the registry, not the individual implementations anymore.

Comment: I think the factory pattern is used incorrectly here.  I would use your `IChatCommunication` interface, and the the `XMLChatCommunication` class.  Instead of adding `XMLChatCommunicationFactory` to the `listBox`, just add `XMLChatCommunication`.  When retrieving the selected, cast it to `IChatCommunication` and you are done.  If you need to delay the initialization of the `IChatCommunication` instance, just create an `init()` method in the interface.

Comment: I also thought about doing something like that first. I feel that an object should not need a call to some kind of `init()` method before it can be used though. Instead, the factory (or the constructor of a `IChatCommunication` object) should do all neccessary preparations. I agree however that you could also replace the factory with that additional `init()` method if you like. After all, the selection of the "best" solution will depend on how the settings (hostname, port, etc.) should be passed through the class structure and how multiple connections with multiple protocols should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance and plain old Java is the 'pattern' to use here.  Instantiate the implementation to be used, and save a reference to it in the object that needs to use it.  When the user switches methods, instantiate the new one.